# Using continuous color scale for symbols/hover text box in Plotly

Tags: colors, plotly, mapbox, scatter

I'm wanting to make a scattermapbox in Plotly where the points are shaped like markers (or any other shape than circles) with the jet continuous colorscale. However, it appears that changing the marker type and the shape are not possible at the same time. Is this the case or am I missing something? Here's my attempt at changing either the hoverlabel textbox or the marker using the continuous color scheme (colors_list is a list of floats between 0 and 1 to be used with the jet colorscale).

Please answer if you know either how to change the color of the hover text box or the marker color (though ideally both would follow the desired jet color scheme). Thanks.

```py
import random
import pandas as pd
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objs as go

import numpy as np

# Create data
random.seed(341)
n = 100
lat = [random.uniform(30, 50) for i in range(n)]
lon = [random.uniform(-130, -100) for i in range(n)]
n_groups = 10 # in reality the number of groups is much larger, so a continuous color scale is necessary
group = random.choices(range(n_groups), k=n)

location_df = pd.DataFrame({'lat': lat, 'lon': lon, 'group': group})

# Public mapbox access token
mapbox_access_token = # add your own token
hover_text = 'custom hover text' 

# Create figure
fig = go.Figure()

## Add trace 

loc_colors = location_df['group']/max(location_df['group'])

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scattermapbox(
        lat=location_df['lat'],
        lon=location_df['lon'],
        mode='markers',
        
        marker=dict(
            colorscale="jet",
            size=12,
            color=loc_colors,
            #symbol='marker' # Does not seem compatible with color
        ),
        hovertext=location_df['group'],
        hoverinfo='text'
    )
)

## General layout

fig.update_layout(
    hovermode='closest',
    width=750, # Size of entire graph
    height=750,
    showlegend=False,
    mapbox=dict(
        accesstoken=mapbox_access_token,
        bearing=10,
        pitch=60,
        zoom=3,
        center=dict(
            lat=np.mean(lat),
            lon=np.mean(lon)
        )
    )
)

fig.show()
```

Current result (can switch between colored circles and marker symbols, but I want colored marker symbols)

[image]

Comment: Do you mind to provide a full [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Comment: The mcve has now been added.

Comment: I think you shared a private token.

Comment: This is happening cos the nature of mapbox symbols see [this](https://community.plotly.com/t/solved-symbol-changes-not-showing-up-with-scattermapbox/16381/2). You can eventually made your own color symbols.